# Sending Html emails using C# code

Tags: c#, .net, html, xml, xslt

I have used the follwing code to transform an xml into html using xsl stylesheet.Now I have to send the generated html as an email to selected people.I don't know how to go about it.Please help!!!

```
    //import name spaces
    using System.Xml.Xsl;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;

    public static void Transform(string XmlPath, string XslPath){

    try{

        //load the Xml doc
        XPathDocument XPathDoc = new XPathDocument(C:\Dibya\svnlog.xml) ;

        XslTransform XslTrans = new XslTransform() ;

        //load the Xsl 
        XslTrans.Load(C:\Dibya\svnlog.xsl) ;

        //create the output stream
        XmlTextWriter Writer = new XmlTextWriter
            ("CommitReport.html", null);

        //do the actual transform of Xml
        XslTrans.Transform(XPathDoc,null, Writer);        

        Writer.Close() ;


    }
      catch(Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't really have anything to do with what you are asking. I think you should get rid of it. And check out the [SMTP Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call

```
string myXmlXsltString = Writer.ToString();
```

To get your xslt transformed xml into a String. You can then [send the email](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx) as per normal, setting the body as the string returned above,eg: message.Body = myXmlXsltString

Comment: Once you've set the message body, you then need to set the IsBodyHtml property: message.IsBodyHtml = true;

Answer (score 0):

Sending email is pretty straightforward in .net and to send an HTML email rather than plain test is just a one line switch

Here is an example for sending email using a gmail account, note the IsBodyHtml setting.

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential loginInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "yyyy");
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
msg.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com", "Admin");
msg.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(sTo, sToDisplayName));
msg.Subject = sSubject;
msg.Body = sBody;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = loginInfo;
client.Send(msg);
```